# Getting StackOverflowException when setting property

Tags: c#, wcf, properties, stack-overflow

```
public List<Empleado> ListarEmpleados()
    {
        List<Empleado> returnList = new List<Empleado>();
        var lista = from u in DB.tabEmpleado
                    select new
                    {
                        u.idEmpleado,
                        u.idUsuario,
                        u.Nombre,
                        u.Apellidos,
                        u.Telefono1
                    };                           
        foreach (var e in lista)
        {
            Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
            empleado.idEmpleado = e.idEmpleado;
            empleado.idUsuario = e.idUsuario;
            empleado.nombre = e.Nombre;
            empleado.apellidos = e.Apellidos;
            empleado.telefono1 = e.Telefono1;
            returnList.Add(empleado);                
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

This is a WCF service, when is called it returns StackOverflow error in the class definition, exactly in the Set property of idEmpleado.

Class definition is here.

```
[DataContract]
public class Empleado
{                
    private int _idEmpleado;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public int idEmpleado
    {
        get { return _idEmpleado; }
        set { idEmpleado = value; } ERROR
    }


    private int _idUsuario;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public int idUsuario
    {
        get { return _idUsuario; }
        set { idUsuario = value; }
    }

    private string _nombre;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string nombre
    {
        get { return _nombre; }
        set { nombre = value; }
    }

    private string _apellidos;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string apellidos
    {
        get { return _apellidos; }
        set { apellidos = value; }
    }

    private string _telefono1;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string telefono1
    {
        get { return _telefono1; }
        set { telefono1 = value; }
    }
}
```

}

Does anybody know where the error is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting the value of the property by calling the property setter again, instead of directly setting its backing field. This causes an infinite recursion and a stack overflow as a result.

```
public int idEmpleado
{
    get { return _idEmpleado; }
    set { idEmpleado = value; } // SHOULD BE _idEmpleado = value
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After editing it, it returns me this error: `code`Element ListadoClientesResult from namespace http://tempuri.org/ cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.`code`

Comment: @Javiere: That's a serialization-related issue. Post it as a separate question and please provide more details, they will be needed.

Comment: Thank you again. Ok, I will write another post.