# C# process terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make this program and after the first output I get the message presented on the image. I’ve   searched around the web and cannot find a way to solve the problem.  Some parts of the program are written in Spanish because y study in a Latin country if any translation is needed please ask.  Any help is much appreciated

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9DTE.png

```
using System;

class Persona
{
    protected string nombre;
    protected string segsoc;
    public Persona()
    {
        nombre = "";
        segsoc = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Objeto Persona construido.");
    }
    ~Persona()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Objeto Persona destruido.");
    }
}

class Empleado : Persona
{
    private double laPagaHora;
    private double lasHoras;
    public new string nombre
    {
        get
        {
            return nombre;
        }
        set
        {
            nombre = value;
        }
    }
    public new string segsoc
    {
        get
        {
            return segsoc;
        }
        set
        {
            segsoc = value;
        }
    }
    public double pagaHora
    {
        get
        {
            return laPagaHora;
        }
        set
        {
            laPagaHora = value;
        }
    }
    public double horas
    {
        get
        {
            return lasHoras;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lasHoras = value;
        }
    }
    public double paga
    {
        get
        {
            return laPagaHora * lasHoras;
        }
    }
    public Empleado()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Objeto Empleado construido.");
    }
    ~Empleado()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Objeto Empleado destruido.");
    }
}

class Demo
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
        Console.WriteLine("\nEntre los datos siguientes.");
        Console.Write("Nombre: ");
        empleado.nombre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Seguro social: ");
        empleado.segsoc = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Paga por hora: ");
        empleado.pagaHora = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Horas trabajadas: ");
        empleado.horas = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("\n--- Datos del empleado ---");
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + empleado.nombre);
        Console.WriteLine("Seguro social: " + empleado.segsoc);
        Console.WriteLine("Paga por hora: {0:C}", empleado.pagaHora);
        Console.WriteLine("Horas trabajadas: " + empleado.horas);
        Console.WriteLine("Paga: {0:C}", empleado.paga);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Press 'Enter' to finish...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting StackOverflowException when setting property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372836/getting-stackoverflowexception-when-setting-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your properties in the Empleado  class are causing this:

```
public new string nombre
    {
        get
        {
            return nombre;
        }
        set
        {
            nombre = value;
        }
    }
```

This will call itself when you set and get a value. Maybe you meant:

```
public new string nombre
    {
        get
        {
            return base.nombre;
        }
        set
        {
            base.nombre = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, calling the property `Nombre` and the field `_nombre` is more compliant and avoids these kind of errors.